# Ruby on Rails Decryption mcrypt_decrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

The following function works perfect in PHP. How can it be translated in Ruby on Rails.

Please note that both privateKey and iv are 32 characters long.

mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $privateKey, base64_decode($enc), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)

Thanking you very much in anticipation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails Decryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104964/ruby-on-rails-decryption) by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ruby-mcrypt](https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt) gem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mcrypt'

crypto = Mcrypt.new(:twofish, :cbc, MY_KEY, MY_IV, :pkcs)

# encryption and decryption in one step
ciphertext = crypto.encrypt(plaintext)
plaintext  = crypto.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use only the specific classes that have those functions.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. I am new to Ruby on Rails. Could you please throw some more light on it?

Comment: What gems do I need to install?

Comment: I have run the following commands at irb command prompt and they return true.  

require "base64"  
require 'hmac-md5'  
require 'crypt/rijndael'  
  
When I use the following  

mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, privateKey, Base64.decode64(enc), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, iv)  
  
I get an error  
  
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Comment: I will be very grateful if you could please tell me how to get the same results in Ruby on Rails as the following php code produces in php

Comment: Is there a Ruby equivalent of MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256? If I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 in PHP and AES-256-CBC in Ruby to encrypt the same data using the same key (32 characters) and iv (32 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I always get different results.

However, if I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in php and AES-256-CBC in Ruby using a key (32 characters) and iv (16 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I get the same results.