# Ruby on Rails Decryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption

The following function works perfect in PHP. How can it be translated in Ruby on Rails.

Please note that both privateKey and iv are 32 characters long.

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $privateKey, base64_decode($enc), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```

I tried to use the following in Ruby but got a bad decrypt error.

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')

cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = privateKey
cipher.iv = iv

decrypted = '' << cipher.update(encrypted) << cipher.final
```

Comment: You're not using this for a password, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here some code which works for me :

```
def decrypt_data(data, pwd, iv)
    encrypted_data = Base64.decode64(data)
    aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
    aes.decrypt
    aes.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(pwd)
    aes.iv = iv
    result = aes.update(encrypted_data) + aes.final 
end
```

In my example the password is encrypted with MD5.

I hope this help

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. However, this does not seem to work for me. I am new to Ruby on Rails. I will be very grateful if you could please tell me how to get the same results in Ruby on Rails as the following php code produces in php

Comment: If I remove + aes.final from the above ruby code, I get a string but it is not readable. I I do not remove + aes.final, I get "bad decrypt" error

Comment: I found this in php doc http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php As you can see, the first comment sais "MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not equivalent to AES_256". This is probably a way...

Comment: MD5 does not encrypt, it hashes.

Comment: I am still not getting the result the php code produces in php :( I am really stuck with this

Comment: All I am getting is this |&���0~�%��]�}w�;�k�Ȱ�*k�tn�:�p�F���p��.Q���5��k�Օ,�z���Ơ��S�:�+(� �G':Y���B##�6��׻?��X^6*�)2��A�u|z?�NH`xAma�j� _�> �>I���&pK-T&����O�{4�m�@pm��C��j&��@�|�O:H�ER�y�vO��U{J~�G�9� �l1�a�h����A���rP!���n $��1�}EA���K�VXU9�1N9�Hl��aN�ۚ�[����b3?L

Comment: While I am expecting this PSID=edc1419e-9f42-41df-b3c2-796ae2c1b5cc&MSISDN=353870011082&CustomString=YOUR_CUSTOM_STRING&Status=Success&LocalCurrency=EUR&LocalCharge=2.500&LocalCharged=2.500&Mode=TEST&LocalPayout=1.068&YourHomeCurrency=EUR&HCCharge=2.500&HCCharged=2.500&HCPayout=1.068&NetworkId=1

Comment: Is there any padding or block size issue?

Comment: Is there a Ruby equivalent of MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256? If I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 in PHP and AES-256-CBC in Ruby to encrypt the same data using the same key (32 characters) and iv (32 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I always get different results.

However, if I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in php and AES-256-CBC in Ruby using a key (32 characters) and iv (16 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You are base64 decoding it in the php example. Are you doing that in the ruby one as well?

```
require "base64"
Base64.decode64(encrypted)
```

Other than that, the code looks right to me.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response  

Here is the complete PHP code  

    $iv = base64_decode($_REQUEST["bpi"]);  
    $enc = $_REQUEST["bpe"];  
    $sig = $_REQUEST["bps"];  
    $sig2 = hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($iv . '.' . $enc), utf8_encode($privateKey));  
    echo(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $privateKey, base64_decode($enc), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));  

It works fine in PHP  

But the above Ruby code gives me a bad decrypt error. I am base64 decoding in ruby as well

Comment: Is there a Ruby equivalent of MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256? If I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 in PHP and AES-256-CBC in Ruby to encrypt the same data using the same key (32 characters) and iv (32 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I always get different results.

However, if I use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in php and AES-256-CBC in Ruby using a key (32 characters) and iv (16 characters) and then base64 encode the encrypted data, I get the same results.