# How can I mcrypt 128 CFB to Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I need to exchange with a PHP API which crypts the requests and answers. On my side I am in rails 4.0.0 (ruby 2.0) and I cannot make it work.

I have read a lot of answers on this subject and have tried to understand how mcrypt works, e.g. http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp, but without success. I still cannot decrypt the encrypted from PHP or encrypt something that the PHP can decrypt

Could you help me please and see what I am doing wrong?

**PHP code:**

```
$secretKey = "1234567891234567";
$encrypt = urlencode( base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt(
             MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
             md5($secretKey),
             $cleartext,
             MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
             $secretKey
           ) ) );

$input = urldecode($input);
$decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                           md5($secretKey),
                           base64_decode($input),
                           MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
                           $secretKey );
```

**Ruby code:**

```
def self.encode(params = {})
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CFB)
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1234567891234567")
  cipher.iv = "1234567891234567"
  encrypted = cipher.update(params.to_query) + cipher.final

  CGI.escape(Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted))
end

def self.decode(answer)
  decrypted = Base64.decode64(CGI.unescape(answer))

  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CFB)
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1234567891234567")
  decipher.iv = "1234567891234567"
  decoded = decipher.update(decrypted) + decipher.final
end
```

Comment: Have you compared the output of the MD5 functions, especially if they are uppercase or lowercase (PS if this solves the issue I would like to post this as an answer)

Comment: That was my first checks, the md5, Base64.encode64 and the urlencode. But for record:
md5 php:  fb77fc7f384d0c2bc555701e57a9e589
md5 ruby: fb77fc7f384d0c2bc555701e57a9e589

Comment: Well, that leaves me stumped. I guess that I can only debug the answer, but that means making sure my PHP and Ruby interpreter are up and running... already voted up.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485437/encrypting-in-php-mcrypt-decrypting-in-ruby-opensslcipher

Comment: Seems like you are using different block sizes, i.e. 128 bits in php and 256 bits in ruby. Try changing AES.new(256, :CFB) to AES.new(128, :CFB) ..

Comment: Hmm I tried without better results. Then I read that MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 != AES(128). AES depends on the key size that's why I put 256....
I also try the padding in my ruby code without results too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `'ncfb'` instead of `MCRYPT_MODE_CFB` in the PHP code. PHP defaults to an 8 bit feed back instead of a feed back of the full block size.

Alternatively you can specify `:CFB8` to be compatible with PHP in Ruby. This one I guessed after reading the documentation for CFB in the OpenSSL documentation.

Many thanks to [this Q/A on IT security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30168/aes-cfb-128-decryption-encryption-problem-between-erlang-and-php) which I only found because I knew what I was looking for.

Comment: `ncfb` - i.e. 128 bit feedback should be preferred.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I put :CFB8 in my ruby code and it works just perfectly as I am not the owner of the PHP code.
Thanks again for your help on this!

Comment: @Stephanie Glad it worked out for you Stephanie. Yes, that's why I edited my answer, it happens quite often that one side is basically pre-defined and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at https://github.com/kingpong/ruby-mcrypt

in your gem file add

`gem "ruby-mcrypt", :lib => "mcrypt"`

**Usage**

```
crypto = Mcrypt.new(:twofish, :cbc, MY_KEY, MY_IV, :pkcs)

# encryption and decryption in one step
ciphertext = crypto.encrypt(plaintext)
plaintext  = crypto.decrypt(ciphertext)

# encrypt in smaller steps
while chunk = $stdin.read(4096)
  $stdout << crypto.encrypt_more(chunk)
end
$stdout << crypto.encrypt_finish

# or decrypt:
while chunk = $stdin.read(4096)
  $stdout << crypto.decrypt_more(chunk)
end
$stdout << crypto.decrypt_finish
```

you can also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489711/1380867

Comment: Oh, wait, now I see what you are showing. Using `mcrypt` for Ruby is fine (OpenSSL is better maintained, but I guess if you use `mcrypt` in PHP...). But you currently don';t match the crypto in the question if you specify twofish, CBC and PKCS padding.