# Different AES implementations don't agree

Tags: javascript, c#, aes, bouncycastle, cryptojs

I have to encrypt a piece of data using both C#, and Javascript. I'm using Bouncy Castle in C# and Crypto-JS in Javascript.

The problem I am facing is that even though all the parameters are equal (OFB with no padding, and the IV is always 0), I don't get the same output with both libraries. The consequence of that is also that I can't decrypt with one what was encrypted with the other.

Here is my C# code for encrypting:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[16];

BufferedBlockCipher aes = new BufferedBlockCipher(new OfbBlockCipher(new AesEngine(), 16));
ParametersWithIV ivAndKey = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(stretchedKey), iv);
aes.Init(true, ivAndKey);

int minSize = aes.GetOutputSize(privateKey.Length);
byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
int length1 = aes.ProcessBytes(privateKey, 0, privateKey.Length, outBuf, 0);
int length2 = aes.DoFinal(outBuf, length1);

byte[] encryptedKey = iv.Concat(outBuf.Take(length1 + length2)).ToArray();
```

My Javascript code is the following for encrypting (try it on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gCHAG/424/):

```
var key = Crypto.util.hexToBytes('59b50e345cab8b6d421b161918ea3fbd7e5921eea7d43d1ac54fa92cca452bb5');
var iv  = Crypto.util.hexToBytes('00000000000000000000000000000000');
var message = Crypto.util.hexToBytes('3b16601d0a7e283c1f24d30ec214676885096cb0bbf3998012a2be87c5a58d89');

var encrypted = Crypto.AES.encrypt(message, key, { iv: iv, asBytes: true, mode: new Crypto.mode.OFB(Crypto.pad.NoPadding) });
```

I get the following from the bouncy castle implementation: `578934dbb576dc986a531f09e8d5abd5b01dc1bfd3ededd222ff8aa6e4bfdbf2`

And the following from Crypto-JS: `578946591ce2d787cbe41bec77a58dac66e6007fb722b1af847ecc3bf4212cea`

Note how the first two bytes are the same, but then everything else is different.

To top it all up, when trying on an online tool, I get a third output (see http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/link/bd243g1VXbD7LUAS/): `57804D64A8...`

I went through everything several times, but I don't see why I get different outputs.

Comment: Actually, in the end I did get to the right value on the given site, but only after making sure auto-detection was off and ensuring that the IV consisted of zero's....but it's for 8 bit output so it would still differ from all three of your given codes (except for the initial 8 bits of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CryptoJS seems to use an output of 128 bits per block for the key stream. You specify 16 *bits* per block for Bouncy. As 8 or 128 bits per block are common for OFB, and since 128 is the recommended output size, I guess you are just confusing bits and bytes in the Bouncy code.

If you specify `new OfbBlockCipher(new AesEngine(), 128)` you should be OK.

Comment: Tested it with BC in Java, normally the C# and Java libs have identical functionality. I did have to do some lowercase to uppercase conversion, but that was about it... Validated against the JCE as well.

Comment: Wow, you're right it works :) I thought this was the number of bytes.

Comment: Well, after [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26518263/589259) it wasn't *that* hard to guess :)

Comment: Small update: NIST doesn't define OFB for a "segment size" other than the full block size (128 for AES) per block. So using anything other than 128 is not standardized for OFB. Segments have only been defined in the current spec for CFB.

Comment: Related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20183/1172 . **Do read the part about OFB!**